# Error 449 in Excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I got the following code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim a As Integer
Dim z As Integer
Dim q As Integer

z=0
q=0

If Target.Address = "$F$2" Then
  z = z + 1
Else
q = 0
End If

If z = 1 Then
ActiveSheet.PrintOut preview:=True
Else
If q = 0 Then
 a = MsgBox("?????", vbYesNo)
 If a = vbNo Then
  Cancel = True
Else ActiveSheet.PrintOut preview:=True
End If
End If
End If
End Sub
```

in the module and I made a button for it and when I press it to run I'm getting this
[image: error]

What do I do to make it right?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've tried to modify a Worksheet_Change event macro into a public sub procedure for use with a button.

A Worksheet_Change has a parameter, *Target* which represents a range object of one or more cells that triggered the worksheet change event. This parameter **has** to be there for the procedure to work in its current form and when used as the original event macro it always does.

When you assign a similar procedure to a button, you are not providing the parameter; i.e. there is no *Target* range object being passed to the procedure hence the error *Argument not optional*.

You cannot simply remove the *Target* parameter as you refer to it later in the code; e.g. `If Target.Address = "$F$2" Then` and there is a message box that depends on the *Target* result. To modify your code into a working condition, you have to decide what you want as a condition that replaces the *F2 is the cell that changed* logical or discard the message box option.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. it did answer a lot of questions. "you have to decide what you want as a condition that replaces the F2 is the cell that changed logical": how do I do this, and by that i mean, can you give an example?

Comment: You need to decide what you are trying to do. There is a confirmation message box in that code. Do you really want it? Does the F2 cell have anything to do with the `ActiveSheet.PrintOut preview:=True` or is it just left over from what that code was originally intended to do?

Comment: it does have something to do with it and i need it there

Comment: i would still need an example of how to make it work